# Problemas consulta select from where SQL en Python y PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Seguramente es una tontería, pero llevo una hora con esto a ver si me pueden ayudar por favor, soy newbie pero colaboro en Earth Science y Chess Exchanges.

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos de postgresql en python. Estoy tratando de mostrar el id de un jugador de poker para un nombre dado. El siguiente código me da como output el id del jugador Bigger2323:

```
hostname = 'localhost'
username = 'postgres'
password = 'dbpass'
database = 'PT4DB'
myConnection = psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, user=username, 
password=password, dbname=database )
cursor = myConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT id_player FROM player WHERE player_name='Bigger2323'""")
print (cursor.fetchall())
```

Sin embargo el siguiente método no funciona y devuelve una lista vacía:

```
def __init__(self):
    jugador = "Bigger2323"
    self.dameIdPlayer(jugador)

def dameIdPlayer(self,jugador):
    hostname = 'localhost'
    username = 'postgres'
    password = 'dbpass'
    database = 'PT4DB'
    myConnection = psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database )
    cursor = myConnection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT id_player FROM player WHERE player_name='"+jugador+"'""")
    print (cursor.fetchall())
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cambia esta linea:

```
cursor.execute(F"SELECT id_player FROM player WHERE player_name='{jugador}'")
```

Comment: Funciona muchas gracias.

Comment: Se aplaude la intención de responder. Sin embargo, una respuesta con solo código es considerada de baja calidad. Te invito a leer [answer] y a editar tu respuesta para agregar una explicación, que puede ser breve, de por qué o cómo tu código resuelve el problema planteado en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo te falta referirte a `jugador` como `self.jugador`

```
def __init__(self):
    self.jugador = "Bigger2323"
    self.dameIdPlayer(self.jugador)

def dameIdPlayer(jugador):
    hostname = 'localhost'
    username = 'postgres'
    password = 'dbpass'
    database = 'PT4DB'
    myConnection = psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database )
    cursor = myConnection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT id_player FROM player WHERE player_name='"+jugador+"'""")
    print (cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: He probado y sigue devolviendo una lista vacía.

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un print a jugador antes de ejecutar la consulta?

Comment: Da "Bigger2323" y hago print (type(jugador)) y da string.